# getting a specific number of bits from a file java

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bit

I am trying to make a code that read blocks of 17 bits from a file and I have no idea of how to get this done, I mean that I will have any file and need to read the next 17 bits to apply a crc algorithm

Comment: How do you represent these 17 bits; in one `int` or in a `byte[]`, or in another way?

Comment: I am trying with a float value, because it have 4 Byte and Int only have 2 Bytes, I need 17 bits, but I have no idea to choose only 17 bits

Comment: No, in Java, `int` always has 32 bits, but it is a signed value. `short` in Java has 16 bits.

Comment: You can't directly do that. But you can read bytes, and put the bits that you didn't use in an int so you can use them the next time you want to read a 17bit thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I felt like programming something this afternoon.

The class `BitReader` below allows you to either read at most 8 bits at a time through the `readBits` method, or 17 bits in one go through the `readBits17` method.

**Source code**

```
public class BitReader {
    private static final int[] MASK = new int[16];
    static {
        for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
            MASK[i] = (1 << i) - 1;
        }
    }

    private InputStream in;

    private int bitsLeft;

    private int bitBuffer;

    public BitReader(InputStream in) {
        this.in = in;
    }

    /**
     * Reads at most 8 bits from the InputStream.
     * 
     * @param bits
     *            between 1 and 8 (inclusive)
     */
    public int readBits(int bits) throws IOException {
        if (bits < 1 && bits > 8)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("bits");
        if (bits > bitsLeft) {
            int r = in.read();
            if (r == -1) {
                throw new EOFException();
            }
            bitsLeft += 8;
            bitBuffer = (bitBuffer << 8) | r;
        }
        int result = bitBuffer >> (bitsLeft - bits);
        bitsLeft -= bits;
        bitBuffer &= MASK[bitsLeft];
        return result;
    }

    public int readBits17() throws IOException {
        return readBits(8) << 9 | readBits(8) << 1 | readBits(1);
    }
}
```

The class `Test` just shows how to use `BitReader`.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // 1 00000010 01000011 = 65536 + 2 * 256 + 67 = 66115
        // Creating a stream that repeats this number twice 
        // 10000001 00100001 1, 10000001 00100001 1
        // 10000001 00100001 11000000 10010000 11[000000] = 129, 33, 192, 144, 192
        byte[] data = { (byte) 129, 33, (byte) 192, (byte) 144, (byte) 192 };
        ByteArrayInputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
        BitReader br = new BitReader(in);
        // Should print 66115, 66115, 0
        System.out.println(br.readBits17());
        System.out.println(br.readBits17());
        System.out.println(br.readBits(6));
    }
}
```

<sub>(Copyright: I hereby place this code in the public domain, for everyone to use as they see fit.)</sub>